# Split string and get the first part with IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data in excel and would like to get the first part (before the "/") if there is a "/". If not, just get the value in the cell. A1 is the raw data and A2 the desired output. Example:

```
A1                A2
------------------------
Yellow / House    Yellow
Car               Car
Green / Cup       Green
Blue / Lamp       Blue
Plate             Plate
Key               Key
```

I am stucked in the following formula:

```
=SE(A1=LOCALIZAR("/";A1;1);=ESQUERDA(A1;LOCALIZAR("/";A1;1));A1")
```

PS.: The formula is in portuguese, but the anwser can be in english. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IFERROR to Deal with the ones without "/":

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),A1))
```

[image]